# Run Kotlin Koans tests from Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

Windows 10, Android Studio 3.0.
So I just cloned Kotlin Koans repo from master branch and tried to run tests in two different ways:
1. Using IDE, when I press the green arrow next to the test method I see:

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "i_introduction._0_Hello_World.N00StartKtTest"Empty test suite.
```

2. And when I try to use terminal as described in Kotlin Koans Readme:

```
gradlew test --tests i_*
```

it gives me an output of:

```
:compileKotlin                                                                   
Using kotlin incremental compilation
Caught an exception trying to connect to Kotlin Daemon
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context
```

I've seen a lot of suggestions that there might be tools.jar missing in jdk folder, I am using internal Android Studios jdk and it's presented here.
I also tried to disable gradle deamons - result is still the same.

Comment: Try importing it as a gradle project as the instructions say.

Comment: I don't know how it should works, but if you write `./gradlew test` in terminal then you'll be able to run separate unit test

Answer (score 1):

If the GitHub version is not working for you, you can also install Kotlin Koans via IntelliJ plugin.

Check out the instruction here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/edu-tools-learner.html

Answer (score 0):

you must use the icon "check task" (*is the check green icon in photo attachment*) on "Task Description" for tests your implementations.
[image]