# Running Kotlin Koan in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Windows 10, Android studio 3.0.1.

Cloned kotlin koans and tried to run a test in Android Studio.  How do I do that?  The doc says "To run use the 'test' icon on the gradle panel".  Um, what gradle panel?  I don't see one, nor any way to bring one up.

Somebody else here asked a similar question ([Run Kotlin Koans tests from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191743/run-kotlin-koans-tests-from-android-studio)), he says he gets a green arrow by the test.  Not seeing any green arrows anywhere.

I'm new to both Android Studio and Kotlin, but have used several other languages and IDEs over the past 40 years or so.

Comment: For the Koans, you should use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). The Community Edition is free and supports everything you need for learning Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the icon "check task" (is the check green icon in photo attachment) on "Task Description" for tests your implementations.
This is repeated here [run-kotlin-koans-tests-from-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191743/run-kotlin-koans-tests-from-android-studio)

[image]